# how to pass Html.TextBox to controller?

Tags: controller, html.textbox

May be this simple. But, I've hard time figuring it out.

I've a controller with different actions that calls the DB code and return result. I want to pass the value of text box to different actions in controller.

How to do it? I know that, I can pass values by using form. But, I don't to know how to call different actions in controller from single view.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem and sorted it. The name of the string argument in Html.TextBox must match the parameter in the controller method it's going to, otherwise the parameters in the controller just end up null.  example:

In the view -

```
<%= Html.TextBox("value") %> // argument is named "value"
```

The controller method -

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ControllerName(string value) // parameter named the same as argument
{ //code here }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language or framework you're using, but in ASP.NET MVC input control IDs map onto action parameters so if you've got a text box:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName/>
```

Then when that form is posted to your action, the framework passes the value of the textbox from the POST data by matching it with the action parameter:

```
public ActionResult UpdateUser(string firstName)
{
  User user = UserManager.UpdateUser(this.CurrentUserId, firstName);
  return View(user);
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I'm using MVC. If I use form, then I'm not sure how to call different action from the same view.

Answer (score 0):

I was browsing and found this question. If those options did not work, maybe you can try

```
Requst["value"]
```

in your controller